# How can I return an object from an SQL query that fits my pydantic schema?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pydantic

## Problem

I am trying to understand how to return an object from an SQL query that will fit the schema of my pydantic models in FastApi. I am able to do this successfully when I use a SQL Alchemy query, but I am unable to do this when I use a Raw SQL query. I could use some help understanding what is different about the two situations.
I've labeled the situations as follows:

> Situation 1: Successful Object Returned Using SQL Alchemy Query

> Situation 2: Failed Attempt to Return Object Using Raw SQL

## Situation 1: Successful Object Returned Using SQL Alchemy Query

```py
  upvote_subquery = select(
      Vote.upvote
    ).where(
      and_
      (Vote.user_id == current_user.id),
      (Vote.post_id == Post.id)
    ).correlate(models.Post)

  posts_query = db.query(
      Post,
      func.count(Vote.post_id).filter(Vote.upvote == True).label("upvotes"),
      func.count(Vote.post_id).filter(Vote.upvote == False).label("downvotes"),
      (upvote_subquery).label('upvote'),
      (Post.owner_id == current_user.id).label("owner")
    ).join(
      Vote, Vote.post_id == Post.id, isouter=True
    ).group_by(
      Post.id
    )
  
  post = post_query.all()
  return posts
```

##### Here is the SQL that this python code translates to

```sql
SELECT 
posts.id AS posts_id,
posts.title AS posts_title,
posts.content AS posts_content,
posts.published AS posts_published,
posts.created_at AS posts_created_at,
posts.owner_id AS posts_owner_id,
count(votes.post_id) FILTER (WHERE votes.upvote = true) AS upvotes,
count(votes.post_id) FILTER (WHERE votes.upvote = false) AS downvotes,
(SELECT votes.upvote 
 FROM votes 
 WHERE votes.user_id = %(user_id_1)s AND votes.post_id = posts.id
) AS upvote,
posts.owner_id = %(owner_id_1)s AS owner 
FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id GROUP BY posts.id
```

This Query returns a list of tuples and each tuple looks like this:

(
<app.models.Post object at 0x112ca3130>,
0,
0,
None,
False
)

## Situation 2: Failed Attempt to Return Object Using Raw SQL

```py
sql = text(
    '''
    SELECT
    posts.id AS posts_id,
    posts.title AS posts_title,
    posts.content AS posts_content,
    posts.published AS posts_published,
    posts.created_at AS posts_created_at,
    posts.owner_id AS posts_owner_id,
    count(votes.post_id) FILTER (WHERE votes.upvote = true) AS upvotes,
    count(votes.post_id) FILTER (WHERE votes.upvote = false) AS downvotes,
    (SELECT votes.upvote 
    FROM votes 
    WHERE votes.user_id = :user_id AND votes.post_id = posts.id
    ) AS upvote,
    posts.owner_id = :user_id AS owner 
    FROM posts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id GROUP BY posts.id
    '''
  )

  posts_query = engine.execute(sql, user_id=current_user.id)
  posts = posts_query.all()
  return posts
```

This Query returns a list of tuples and each tuple looks like this:

(
57,
'Another Post',
'Another Post',
True,
datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 9, 20, 9, 8, 260773, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400))),
1,
0,
0,
None,
False
)

## My Question

The two queries, when viewed in there SQL format seem to be nearly identical with the exception of the syntax for placeholders. Is there some reason why the Raw SQL query does not return <app.models.Post object at 0x112ca3130> in its tuples, and if so, is there a way to get the Raw SQL query to return <app.models.Post object at 0x112ca3130> in its tuples? I want the query to return:

> (
> <app.models.Post object at 0x112ca3130>,
> 0,
> 0,
> None,
> False
> )

because my schema for the data looks like this:

```py
class PostOut(BaseModel):
  Post: Post
  upvotes: int
  downvotes: int
  upvote: Optional[bool]
  owner: bool

  class Config:
    orm_mode = True
```

Post contains the relevant data that is contained in <app.models.Post object at 0x112ca3130>

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and consider any advice or possible solutions to my issue. If I can do anything to clarify the problem, please let me know!

Comment: Why do you want to use a raw query? It looks like you already have a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @HernánAlarcón I want to use a raw SQL query because some of my other queries are more complicated than this current example and I cannot understand how to execute them using SqlAlchemy (I am more confident writing Raw SQL). This example is just a simple example version of a more complex query that I cannot understand, but the basic issue is the same.

Comment: This question is pretty complex, will be difficult for us to provide meaningful support. Is it possible to simplify the Q? (Perhaps drawing on a simplified use case, I understand it won't be a 100% match to what you're fully trying to do.)